# Copying a character map from host memory to device in CUDA

Tags: c, arrays, memory, cuda, malloc

Unsure on how to copy this from host memory to device memory, been working on this for some time now and just making no progress, any help big or little would be greatly appreciated.

```
 unsigned char map[256] = {

   8,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,
   0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,
   0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 };
```

Would it be similar to this?

```
cudaMalloc(&d_n, sizeof(int));

  cudaMemcpy(d_n, &h_n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  kernel <<<16,16>>>(d_n);

  cudaThreadSynchronize();

  cudaMemcpy(&h_n, d_n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  

  cudaFree(d_n);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you know how to copy an array of, for example, 'int's? If not, then you should start by reading the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory).

Comment: If you want to have it in global memory then yes, you can use cudaMemcpy.   Which error are getting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a segfault in your code, this can be due to the following mistake  :

1. You are using `sizeof(int)` to copy an array of unsigned char.
2. Is `h_n` your array called "`map`" ? an `unsigned char[]` is a pointer, you can use it directly in `cudaMemcpy` method.

   `cudaMemcpy(d_n, map, 256 * sizeof(unsigned char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`

should work.